# How to decode JSON Object in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

Can anyone help me how to decode JSON object from Rails. Basically I have javascript function that encode JSON object and pass it to rails.

```
function save(){
----
----   
notesArray.push({ Index: i, Title: title.val(), Content: content.val()});

// json encode it
var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(notesArray);

//sending to rails
$.post('monkey', {notes: jsonStr});
}
```

I don't know how to decode this in my controllers in Rails. I also want it to save it in my database(SQLite). Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 4):

```
obj = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(json_string)
```

But it's slow, check out this for a much faster extension: http://flori.github.com/json/